# Firefox doesn't restore sessions

Tags: firefox

Every now and then when I open Firefox it doesn't restore the previous session. What's even more irritatiing is that I can't seem to restore any previous sessions manually because the history is gone. It doesn't matter wether it's an unexpected shutdown or not. When I look in the folder `sessionstore-backups` there aren't any sessions except for the current one. No older sessions are saved.

My browsing history however is still available so I can access most of the tabs one by one, but all my sessions are completely gone. This is starting to be quite annoying, especially since it seems to occur at completly random.

Any ideas? I have checked that FF is supposed to restore previous session and it works - mostly.

Comment: Do you get a message that Firefox has a problem restoring the session, or it just opens a new session with just your start tab?  What OS?  What version of FF?  Have you checked your drive for corruption?  Have you tried creating a fresh profile?

Comment: @fixer1234 No error message, just new session, W8.1, ver 63.03 (64-bit), no corrupt drive. Created fresh profile but can't manually recreate the error.

Comment: When you say you can't manually recreate the error, do you mean that there is no error with the fresh profile, or that the problem is unpredictable and you don't know whether the fresh profile has the issue?  If you were just to switch to the new profile, how long would you need to go without a recurrence to be confident that the problem was gone?

Comment: @fixer1234 No error with the new profile and the problem is very unpredictable. I don't know what causes it. It can happen again after a week or two months. There is no clear pattern.

Comment: Erratic behavior in Firefox is typically from a couple of sources.  One is add-ons; either an add-on with bugs, incompatibilities between multiple add-ons, or incompatibilities between add-ons and stuff running in the background.  The other is corruption.  V63 is pretty recent.  If you had the symptom before updating to v63, it probably isn't corruption in the Firefox application.  If it just started after updating to v63, rule out application corruption by uninstalling FF and reinstalling it from a fresh download.  That shouldn't affect your profile.  (cont'd)

Comment: Creating a new profile is a simple way to rule out profile corruption.  You can use the sync feature to load everything from your original profile.  That doesn't copy potentially corrupted profile contents, it recreates everything in the new profile.  I would start with that and just use it for awhile.  If the problem recurs, it will require detective work to disable add-ons, test, and re-enable add-ons in a controlled manner over time to identify the culprit.  Unfortunately, diagnosing a problem that recurs very infrequently can be a pain in the butt and requires a lot of patient waiting.

Comment: One other thought: do you normally keep an insane number of tabs open?  When it fails to restore the session, what is the ballpark number of tabs that should have been restored?  Also, one other situation I've run into.  If you have your normal session with a bunch of tabs, then you open another FF window, then close the original window with all of your tabs before closing the new window.  FF remembers that the session ended with a window with one tab.  Even with Restore Session set, it won't restore the session for one tab.

Comment: @fixer1234 I do have several tabs open often, but I try to keep them under ten. Opening a second window and closing FF is something I'm familiar with. This is the only situation where I know what caused it. But other the times i know I didn't have multiple windows open.